# Having problems checking AND using dialog input

Tags: java, joptionpane, parseint

I'm just starting to learn java. It's a bit neat, but I'm hitting a wall with something I imagine to be painfully simple. Here's part of what I'm working on:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawingShapes extends JApplet
{
  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    int rgb = 0;
    boolean useful = false;
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Make this easy for me.\n"
    +"Type an integer between 0 and 255");
    do
    {
      try
      {
        rgb = Integer.parseInt( number );
        if (rgb > 0 && rgb < 255)
        {
          useful = true;
        }
        else
        {
          useful = false;
        }
      }
      catch ( NumberFormatException nfe )
      {
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "\"" + number + "\""
        + " is not an integer between 0 and 255!\n"
        + "Lrn2 be doin' it right!" );
      }
    }
    while ( !useful );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The integer is " + rgb);
  }
}
```

The idea is that the dialog asks for a number, and if it is not a number shows an error and asks again. That works nicely now, actually. What I want, though, is to use that number (rgb) to create a shade of gray that's used in an applet outside this class.

```
Color shade = new Color(rgb,rgb,rgb);
```

That doesn't work because it cannot read the variable from inside another class. Or, it probably can, but I think I need help figuring out how.

In short, I need to read input, verify it, and still be able to use it for something else later. I'm falling a bit short of this goal, so I come to stackoverflow in seek of guidance.

EDIT: Dans suggestion really helped me with the variables, but now I'm having a problem of not being able to draw the graphics. The applet closes right after the Dialog is exited. So I'm still a bit stumped. I just need some simple shapes drawn, using the color from the input dialog for the background. The last half of the code looks like this now:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new DrawingShapes().getColor();
  }
  public class Shade
  {
    private int color;
    public void setColor(int col)
    {
      color = col;
      System.out.println(color);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics canvas)
    {
      int col = color;
      Color gray = new Color(col,col,col);
      setBackground(gray)
      setSize(500, 500);  
      canvas.drawOval(0, 0, 500, 500);
      canvas.draw....[blablabla other shapes]
    }
  }
```

It completely skips the paint option unless I comment out everything leading up to it...

Comment: never ever change the state of a component in the paint cycle!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below for a potential solution. I created a new class called Shade that has a private field that can be set from another class (your class or any other) using a public setter method.

Please note that I changed your class a little bit as it is not nice having everything in the main method, which is static.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DrawingShapes extends JApplet {
  private Shade shade = new Shade();

  private void readColor() {
    int rgb = 0;
    boolean useful = false;
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Make this easy for me.\n" + "Type an integer between 0 and 255");
    do {
      try {
        rgb = Integer.parseInt(number);
        if (rgb > 0 && rgb < 255) {
          useful = true;
          shade.setColor(rgb);
        } else {
          useful = false;
        }
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\"" + number + "\"" + " is not an integer between 0 and 255!\n"
            + "Lrn2 be doin' it right!");
      }
    } while (!useful);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The integer is " + rgb);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DrawingShapes().readColor();
  }

  public class Shade {
    private int color;

    public void setColor(int col) {
      color = col;
      System.out.println("The chosen color shade is " + color);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reviewing it! My issue with the variables seems solved, now I just need to get the Graphics working now!